# CodeIgniter: storing sessions in DB, how to know who session came from?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm thinking of storing CI sessions in the database so I can display how many users are currently online, who specifically is online, etc.

Looking at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html, am I right in my understanding that information would be stored in the `user_data` column of the `ci_session` table? Meaning, maybe I just store the user's id in there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CodeIgniter will store the data in the table you specify in your config file. By default, it's `ci_session`. The session information, what is accessible through `$_SESSION` for instance, is serialized and saved in a column named `user_data`. That field will not be able to tell you whether or not the session has expired (or in other words, how many people are online).

What you could do instead is use the `last_activity` column, which is a timestamp of the last time that session was active. You could run a SQL query that selects the count of `session_id` where the `last_activity` is less than 2 minutes ago.

```
SELECT COUNT(`session_id`) AS `active_user_count` FROM `ci_session` WHERE `last_activity` >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
```

With that said, an existing session doesn't necessarily mean that the user is "signed in". If you need to check that they're signed in, you can use a `LIKE` operator to add a condition to the `WHERE` statement that checks if a user is signed in. This will depend on what variable name you're using so have a look at your data and see if you can figure it out.

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(`session_id`) AS `active_user_count` FROM `ci_session` WHERE `last_activity` >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) AND `user_data` LIKE '%s:9:"logged_in";b:1;%'
```

Comment: can you elaborate on `LIKE '%s:9:"logged_in";b:1;%'`? It looks strange. I thought it might just be a simple, straightforward value in there.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie - The `LIKE` coupled used used to search for a particular "string" in a field. In this case, I'm using the wildcard character (the % symbol) in the front and back to instruct MySQL that there may be additional text before and after the string I'm looking for. The data in `user_data` is serialized (look at [http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)). For example, the `s:9:"logged_in";` is the PHP serialized representation of a "string" (s) of 9 characters which is "logged_in". Yours may be different.

Comment: Ah, it's serialized. I didn't recognize it as being serialized. Does `user_data` contain all the session variables of a particular user?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie - Yes. The entire `$_SESSION` variable is serialized.

Answer (score 3):

This works! use it

```
    $session = $this->db->get('ci_sessions')->result_array();
    foreach ($session as $sessions) {
        $sessio = $sessions['last_activity'] + 7200;
        echo $sessio . "time";
        echo now();
        echo "||";
        $custom_data = $this->session->_unserialize($sessions['user_data']);

        if (is_array($custom_data)) {
            foreach ($custom_data as $key => $val) {
                $user[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($user);
    exit();`
```